# Change the order of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, momentjs

I'm working with an XML data that gives all information for my vue app. Everything works fine except one value.

I need to get the date from an element, but it comes in this format :

```
['2022-10-25']
```

It should be 25-10-2022

I get this item using :

```
item.datum.join().toString()
```

How can I change it ?

Since it's an Object, I can not find a solution for this, better would be to handle it as data, I have MomentJS installed but I also did not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to to this is `split` the string by the character `"-"` to an array which we `reverse` and `join` it togheter with `"-"`.

Or use moment if you have it installed already.

```js
// result step 1
console.log('2022-10-25'.split("-"));
// result step 2
console.log('2022-10-25'.split("-").reverse());
// final result
console.log('2022-10-25'.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
// with moment.js
console.log(moment('2022-10-25').format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you simply reverse the string?

```
const dates = ['2022-10-25']
const desiredDate = dates[0].split('-').reverse().join('-')
```